# Event on click document in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to perform logic when the contents of an iframe are clicked, the content of the iframe is a pdf located within the same domain.

I can perform the task on the iframe, which allows selecting of the border, but not it's contents. I've tried a number of different ways, my latest:

```
$(function () {
            $("#iframePDF").contents().click(function (e) {
                alert("test");
            });
        });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

$(document.getElementById('iframePDF').contentWindow.document)

Comment: It works without a "src", but when the pdf is embedded it no longer works.

Comment: so what are you trying to click on exactly? is the pdf embedded?

Comment: I'll mark as correct, I went a different way. I converted the pdf to an image which simplified the process. Thanks.